# Saving Data on a ViewController (When moving away or to the ViewController)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an app in which the 1st ViewController has 5 textfields where I insert data and then move to next controller. But when I comeback after selecting the first ViewController, the textfield doesn't contain any data. This is done through present view controller. I don't know how to handled it....

Comment: Update your question with code. Then we can help you.

Comment: You need to remember data of the `TextField`, and after returning to the controller again to complete the `TextField` with the old data

Comment: problem is simple that textfiled data ramain while  move to another controller or not

Comment: How are you moving to the next view controller and how are you returning?

Comment: var next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nextControoler") as! UIViewController
        self.presentViewController(next, animated: true, completion: nil

Comment: And how are you returning to the first ViewController?

Comment: var back = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("backController") as! UIViewController self.presentViewController(back, animated: true, completion: nil

Answer (score 1):

when going back you instantiate a completely new viewcontroller instead of really going back to your old one. that is why the textfields are empty. so instead of

```
var back = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("backController") as! UIViewController self.presentViewController(back, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

try

```
presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think we're all having trouble understanding your problem.

From what I've understood, you want to save/access the data that was typed into the textField at a later point: *if you move to or from another viewController you want the data to still we saved from when you typed it.* Correct? (You should also create a label where the text will be displayed after being added to the textField.)

If this is the case, you should use **Core Data/NSUserDefaults** for this or **Parse**.

Either one of the two can help you save the data.

Here is a link for the tutorial on CoreData using Swift 2. However, I would *not* recommend CoreData. Not sure what your purposes are but this may work perfectly for you!: http://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial

I personally use and would recommend using Parse.

Go to Parse.com, created a new account. Download this project: http://www.robpercival.co.uk/parse-working-on-xcode-7swift-2/ and then look at the docs at this link for how to create and store objects so that when moving to and from different ViewControllers your dad stays there and is saved, no matter if you quit the app or changed ViewControllers!: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects

Let me know if this helped and how I can update the question.

Comment: Hey, did this help? Let us know which answer better suits your needs. @ShahbazAkram